# I tried deploying the react app in heroku but it failed

Tags: reactjs, heroku

This is the error that I got. It says run the npm bugs reminderpro. I did that but nothing works. My code has sfcookies from npm. When i deployed earlier it said that sfcookies did not download.... something like that. So i tried typing sfcookies on package.json under dependencies but that did not work too. Now is there a SPECIFIC way to put these on heroku, am i missing somehting. (I used create-react-app for initial installation)

```
 remote: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-128-generic
    remote: npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_d018c5494b246e95e5185c9297b315ce/.heroku/node/                                                                                                                                  bin/node" "/tmp/build_d018c5494b246e95e5185c9297b315ce/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "ru                                                                                                                                  n" "build"
    remote: npm ERR! node v6.11.3
    remote: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
    remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    remote: npm ERR! reminderpro@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
    remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
    remote: npm ERR!
    remote: npm ERR! Failed at the reminderpro@0.1.0 build script 'react-scripts bui                                                                                                                                  ld'.
    remote: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm instal                                                                                                                                  led.
    remote: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reminderpro p                                                                                                                                  ackage,
    remote: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    remote: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    remote: npm ERR!     react-scripts build
    remote: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this projec                                                                                                                                  t with:
    remote: npm ERR!     npm bugs reminderpro
    remote: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    remote: npm ERR!     npm owner ls reminderpro
    remote: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
    remote:
    remote: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/build_d018c5494b246e95e5185c9297b315ce/npm-debug.log
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) mult                                                                                                                                  i app.
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !       Push rejected to sheltered-plateau-76958.
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reminderpro",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.13",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the build script being called before the install?

You should show the code for your package.json as I could better get a grasp of the order Heroku calls your scripts.

Comment: Okay I have added package.json. Sorry I did not get the install part ?

Comment: Try moving all your packages from devDependencies to under your dependencies.

Comment: ahhhh I dont see devDependencies there ?